# How to copy files from one directory to another on the same server using FileZilla?

Tags: filezilla

I want to copy files from one directory to another on the same server using FileZilla. Please guide me how can it be done?

Answer (score 26):

FileZilla does not support duplication (copying) of remote files. Neither by drag&drop nor any other way (menu, keyboard shortcut).

---

One of the reasons is a lack of support for this operation in majority of the FTP and SFTP servers. There's actually no standard way to duplicate a remote file over FTP or SFTP protocol. Some FTP and SFTP servers support proprietary or non-standard extensions for this though.

---

Some FTP/SFTP clients do support remote file duplication. Either using the extension or via a temporary local copy of the remote file.

For example [WinSCP SFTP/FTP client](https://winscp.net/) does [support the duplication](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_move_duplicate) using both drag&drop and menu/keyboard command:

- It supports the `SITE CPFR`/`CPTO` FTP extension (supported for example by [ProFTPD `mod_copy` module](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_copy.html))
- It supports the [`copy-file` and `copy-data` SFTP extensions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00#section-6) (supported for example by [ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html), Bitvise and OpenSSH [since 9.0]).
- It falls back to automatic duplication via a local temporary copy, if the above extensions are not available.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Some mistake *copy* and *move*. Moving a file between two remote directories is widely supported by SFTP and FTP servers and clients. In FileZilla (or WinSCP), just drag the file between the folders to move it.

Answer (score 9):

One obvious solution is to download the file to a temporary local directory and upload it to the target directory.

It's not always possible for you to write to the target directory if your account does not have write access. So "copying" to the target directory is not always possible.

Comment: FileZilla doesn't have a copy option?

Comment: I haven't seen such an option myself. e.g. if you drag&drop from one remote server to another (possibly the same server), FileZilla won't allow it, as of 3.14.

Comment: If one drag and drop file from one directory to another, it gets moved not copied.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I am using version 3.14.0.

Comment: While dragging the file (even when holding `Ctrl`) FileZilla always shows the `+` icon. This is misleading because it moves the file - no copy. FileZilla 3.28.0

Answer (score 2):

It’s like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808815/1025421) says: FTP simply doesn’t support remote copying. If only FTP access is available you’ll have to download the file and upload it again, to the desired location.

Answer (score -1):

2021 Yes if u have the remote site set up as two windows and drag from lower window files to upper window (remote site)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgwxG.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).